# Golang plugin build fails "unsupported load command 0x80000034"

Tags: go, apple-m1, apple-silicon

Development environment: MacOS M1, Go1.18(darwin arm64/amd64), GoLand

I'm trying to implement a plugin API that can manipulate the data of the original process.

When I first tried to run and debug the code, the arm version compiler showed an error like this

```
Build Error: go build -o /Users/seungyeoplee/Workspace/pluginDemo/main/__debug_bin -gcflags all=-N -l .
# server
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link: /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link: running strip failed: exit status 1
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/strip: error: unsupported load command (cmd=0x80000034) (exit status 2)
```

I did some research about this issue, but I couldn't find any appropriate answers.
The things that I couldn't understand most was that 'go run main.go' command works running the code and even amd64 version of compiler works to build the project.

It showed expected output:

```
hi
start
load plugins
go.mod
demo.go
```

Since I could test the project with amd version compiler, I tried to compile demo.go plugin. But, this time, both couldn't compile demo.go plugin, with the same "unknown load command (cmd-0x80000034)" error message.

I would be appreciated if anyone can point me out what's occuring the error, or what else I can do to prevent this error.

Project Structure:

```
├── demo
│   ├── go.mod
│   └── demo.go
├── main
│   ├── go.mod
│   ├── main.go
│   └── server
└── plugin
    ├── constants.go
    ├── general.go
    ├── go.mod
    ├── plugin.go
    └── process.go
```

Since plugin cannot import executable module, process execution is performed by external module.
main/main.go

```
package main

import (
     "almeng.com/plugin"
)

func main() {
    println("hi")
    process := &plugin.Process{}
    process.Start()
}
```

File loading part is implemented in general.go and showed no error so far. When process loading plugins, it passes itself as a pointer so that plugin can access and manipulate the process's data.
plugin/process.go

```
package plugin

import _plugin "plugin"

type Process struct { plugin []Plugin }

func (p *Process) Log(msg string) { println(msg) }
func (p *Process) Start() {
    println("start")
    p.LoadPlugins()
}

func (p *Process) LoadPlugins() {
    println("load plugins")
    files := loadFolder("../demo")
    plugins := ExtAll(files, "so")
    for _, pl := range plugins { p.LoadPlugin(pl.Name()) }
}

func (p *Process) LoadPlugin(entry string) {
    plugin_file, err := _plugin.Open(entry)
    if err != nil { return }
    plug, _ := plugin_file.Lookup("plugin")
    pl := plug.(Plugin)
    pl.Init(p)
    err = pl.OnLoad()
    if err != nil {
        println(err.Error(), pl.Name())
        return
    }
    p.plugin = append(p.plugin, pl)
}
```

plugin/plugin.go

```
type Plugin interface {
    Name() string
    OnLoad() error
    OnUnload() error
    Init(process *Process) Plugin
}

// Formal appearance of plugin structure
type plugin struct {
    process     *Process
    name        string
}
```

This is a test code of an actual plugin. Its initialization method receives pointer of the process and I was trying to see if calling its method is possible.
demo/demo.go

```
package main

import (
    plug "almeng.com/plugin"
)

type Plugin struct {
    name string
    process *plug.Process
}

var plugin = &Plugin{}

func (p Plugin) Init(process *plug.Process) plug.Plugin {
    plugin.name = "hello"
    plugin.process = process
    return plugin
}

func (p Plugin) Name() string {return p.name}
func (p Plugin) OnLoad() error {
    p.process.Log(p.Name())
    return nil
}
func (p Plugin) OnUnload() error {return nil}
```

Comment: How _exactly_ are you building the project? The error is coming from `/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/strip`, which is not a part of the go toolchain.

Comment: I tried to build it with the latest google go compiler. `go version go1.18 darwin/arm64
go build
`

Comment: I think the error is happening while linking

Comment: You said that `go run` works, which must call `go build` first to build the binary, so there must be something different when this fails. It's also unclear why it's trying to call the external `strip` command at all, which is not part of the normal linking process.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's calling `strip` command, but I found that the error was llvm's. After reading your comment, I updated llvm, and it fixed the problem.